# Java casting from int to char acting weird

Tags: java, casting

I am trying to cast xored ints to chars. If I only cast an int it gets converted to an a correct char. But if I xor two characters and cast their result I get integer value. Why?

```
public class ClassToTestSnippets {

    private static ClassToTestSnippets ctts;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ctts = new ClassToTestSnippets();
        ctts.testThisMethod();
    }

    public void testThisMethod() {
        System.out.println((char) 244^128);
        System.out.println((char) 116);
        System.out.println(244^128);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its first converting 244 to character and then try to xor with 128 which is equivalent to your third print statement.

```
System.out.println((((char) 244) ^128));//this is how it interprets.
System.out.println((char) 116);
System.out.println(244^128);
```

Answer (score 6):

Because of [Operator Precedence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

First the *cast* will be performed, then the `int` will be *implicitly* cast to `char`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add parentheses so the result of your XOR and not only the first argument will be converted to char.

```
 System.out.println((char) (244^128));
```